# Automapper: Missing type map configuration .NET Web API

Tags: c#, .net, api, mapping, automapper

i am currently using a .NET Web Api, to get a list of Counties based on Countries.
While attempting to GET the Counties, I get the "Automapper: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping" exception.

My Domain Class is :

```
 public class County
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CountryId { get; set; }

        public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<City> City { get; set; }
    }
```

My DTO is

```
 public class CountyResponse
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string CountryId { get; set; }
    }
```

Mapping profile :

```
public class CountyProfile : Profile
    {
        public CountyProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<CountyResponse, County>().ReverseMap();
        }
    }
```

My Service Class GetAlLMethod:

```
 public async Task<Result<List<CountyResponse>>> GetAllAsync()
        {
            var counties = _context.Counties.ToListAsync();
            var mappedCounties = _mapper.Map<List<CountyResponse>>(counties);
            return await Result<List<CountyResponse>>.SuccessAsync(mappedCounties);
        }
```

Builds Ok, and I also have the Country domain mapped exactly the same (1:1).
Yet, one works, while this one, when trying to access the Get Endpoint, i get this error.
Any idea what is wrong here ? (the services are registered - I am using the following to inject them :

```
 public static void AddInfrastructureMappings(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mapping a task (the result of your ToListAsync) to a list of your DTO which fails. You need to await your query so you get the result of the task, then the mapping will work properly

```
        var counties = await _context.Counties.ToListAsync();
        var mappedCounties = _mapper.Map<List<CountyResponse>>(counties);
```

Comment: Goddamit! It was that simple... and i said it's 1:1 to the Country case... well, that one had the await there!

Comment: Yes, sometimes we miss obvious things. Please mark the answer if it helped you